# Kendo UI grid filtering via DropDownList instead of MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The following snippet uses a MultiSelect field to filter through an array of items. Filtering only occurs when items have been selected in the MultiSelect and the 'Filter' button has been clicked.
http://jsbin.com/iVIQoKiV/1/edit

How can it be set up using a DropDownList instead? Also, once an item has been selected in the DropDownList, how can the grid be filtered instantly without the need  to click a button?

**Edit:**

Here's a new [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oTUCEhA/2/edit). Managed to implement a DropDownList. I've used the following change event but now filtering doesn't work:

```
change: function() {
  var value = dropdown.value();
  if (value) {
  grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
      field: "Territories",
      operator: function (itemValue) {
      var matchingItem = itemValue.find(function (item) {
        return $.inArray(item.TerritoryID, value) >= 0;
      });
        return matchingItem !== null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello just the same scenario is covered in the Toolbar Grid online demo [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html). It filters instantly beucase it uses the change event of the DropDownList to invoke the filter method immediately.

Comment: Managed to adapt the code to the change event but filtering doesn't work now. I've posted the change code above.